# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] using angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs

I have this piece of code and I am trying to use `groupBy` Filter. But as soon as I try to load `angular-filter.js`, I get the above mentioned error.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Group By Data</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--<div ng-controller="dataController">
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in properties | groupBy: 'name'">
  Group name: {{ key }}
  <li ng-repeat="prop in value">
    player: {{ prop.name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
    </div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('app',['angular.filter'])
.controller('dataController', function($scope)
{
    $scope.properties = [
     {name: 'Weight', Property: 'quintal', value:'50'},
     { name: 'Quanity', Propertys: 'L' , value:'40'},
     { name: 'Quantity', Property: 'ml' , value:'10'},
     { name: 'Height', Property: 'metres' , value:'10' },
     { name: 'Height', Property: 'cm' , value:'20'},
     {name: 'Height', Property: 'inches' , value:'30'},
     { name: 'Size', Property: 'Fat' , value:'28' },
     { name: 'Size',Property: 'Slim', value:'48' },
     { name: 'Feature', Property: 'Sharp' , value:'9'},
     { name: 'Feature', Property: 'Bland', value:'2' },
     {name: 'Weight', Property: 'KG', value:'10'},
     { name: 'Weight', Property: 'grams', value:'20' },
     { name: 'Weight', Property: 'ton' , value:'30'}

];
});
```

Comment: You must be missing something because I don't see where you're including your own script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to include `angular.filter` in the controller. It's already defined in `angular.min.js file`. you don't worry about that one. Just write

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('dataController', function($scope, $filter)
{
  if you want use filter just inject and then use

    //$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
});
```

Comment: I see other threads saying that "orderBy comes out of the box, but not groupBy; you need to load angular.filter".  The OP was specifically asking about groupBy.  I'm using 1.4.7, and my angular.min.js does not appear to have it; adding $filter as a dependency is not finding groupBy